# IIS running but not serving content

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I have an internal dev server running Windows 2k8 R2 with the Web and FTP Server roles set up which won't serve any content at all.

Trying to connect from another host via telnet yields 'connection failed':

```
c:\>telnet devserver 80
Connecting To devserver...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Conn
```

ect failed

Using `netstat -an | find "80"` on the dev server returns no connections on port 80 (a few on 1801, etc)

[tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) confirms this, listing no open connections on port 80.

The following services related to the Web role are running:

- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Application Host Helper Service
- Microsoft FTP Service (ftp connections to port 21 are granted)
- Windows Process Activation Service

The default website bindings are:

```
Type    Host Name    Port    IP Address    Binding Information
http                 80      *             
net.tcp                                    808:*
net.pipe                                   *
net.msmq                                   localhost
msmq.formatname                            localhost
```

When setting up a new application under the default site, the test function passes both connection/authorisation only if the 'connect as' user is local admin, otherwise the test errors with 'invalid application path'.

At no point is the W3SVC service PID bound to port 80 (it is running and bound to 21 for ftp).

There are no W3SVC log directory at `c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\` (only FTPSVC2), and no HTTPERR directory at `c:\windows\system32\` or `c:\windows\system32\logfiles\`.

There do not appear to be any related errors in the event logs.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts on be a good place dig into what's (not) going on here!

Comment: Can you confirm that HTTP connections on port 80 are at least leaving the server?  A netstat -ano would tell you if the port is being leveraged locally or not.  Please post the output.  Are you sure that IIS is installed correctly?  The only other thing I would recommend if IIS is not installed correctly is to flatten and rebuild the entire server.

Comment: Can confirm there are no connections on port 80, originating local or remote. I'd rather not post netstat output from internal hosts, were you looking for something in particular I could provide? I'm getting the feeling that there is something 'just wrong' with the install - to be honest as it's a dev box I'm interested in trying to dig down and figure out what's going on as a learning ex for myself and others. IIS *appears* to be installed correctly, though I wouldn't vouch for it. Unsure how to check. Is there any approach I can take to trying to get any info at all out of the W3SVC process?

Comment: You can always remove any ip addresses with some other form of words or nnumbers if you don't want to show the workings of your internal environment.

Answer (score 1):

At this point given the additional information provided with your initial post it would be wiser just to flatten and rebuild the entire server from the ground up.  It's a lot easier than going under the hood of the operating system to hack and slash your registry/files.  Don't re-invent the wheel here.  Just get rid of this install and start over.  If it happens again, look at your hardware/drivers.